# Can't delete meters on htop with the delete key

Tags: macos, terminal, htop

When customizing htop my setup through the F2 menu, I accidentally put up some unwanted meters. I tried using backspace/delete according to the bottom menu, but it didn't affect the entry. I'm using Mac OS X, if that matters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found that on a mac keyboard you could use the **<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>** to remove column entries from the setup menu.

Comment: This worked for `htop` on a remote Linux machine where my Mac's Delete key wasn't working on its own.

Answer (score 10):

My solution was (iterm2 using natural keys) to us <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> to remove column entries from the setup menu.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to delete the htop configuration file using

```
rm -fv ~/.config/htop/htoprc
```

While certainly not a true solution, it is a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Both <kbd>Fn</kbd>+**<kbd>⇧</kbd>**+<kbd>Delete</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> work with `iTerm2` (Build 3.3.10beta4).

My key bindings are also set to natural keys:
Preferences **»** Keys **»** Key Bindings

And:  Profiles **»** `{Profile Name}` **»** Keys **»** Presets….

Typing **<kbd>⇧</kbd>** feels faster, easier, and more natural.

Comment: YESSSSSSS! Finally I'm able to remove those bl00dy CPU bars that take up 1/2 the screen. Thank you, thank you thank you  

Comment: Works in 2022. Thanks!